# Element should have been "select" but was "li"

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I am trying to get selenium to go thought the drop down and verify every single option within the drop drop. I have tried using the Xpath, but still no luck. Also if there's a way to clean up my array without hard coding all the options that would be great. The following is my code:

```
    Googledriver.get("http://www.lolesports.com/en_US/"); 
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    String arr[]= {"NA LCS", "EU LCS", "LCK", "LPL", "LMS", "NA CHALLENGER", "EU CHALLENGER", "RIFT RIVALS", "MID-SEASON INVITATIONAL", "ALL-STAR EVENT"};      
    Select choices = new Select(Googledriver.findElement(By.className("dropdown-nav")));

    List<WebElement> dropdownvalues=choices.getOptions();   
    System.out.println(dropdownvalues.size());

    for(int i=0;i<dropdownvalues.size();i++)
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(dropdownvalues.get(i).getText(), arr[i]);
    }
```

Comment: please share  the HTML file you're working with, because we can't see what dropdown your talking about

Comment: http://www.lolesports.com/en_US/? Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Since there is not ``"select"`` in your ``arr`` array, i doubt that this is the failing test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebElement` which you are trying to assign to a `Select` Class object is not within `select` tag. Hence it shows an error as `Element should have been “select” but was “li”`

Though you havn't exactly mentioned your exact validation point in your Question but I assume you are trying to validate the items like `NA LCS`, `EU LCS`. For that we need to loop through the several `<a>` tags as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver Googledriver = new ChromeDriver();
Googledriver.get("http://www.lolesports.com/en_US/"); 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Googledriver, 10);
WebElement more_comp = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='main-nav-menu']/li[@class='dropdown-nav']")));
more_comp.click();
List<WebElement> listValues = Googledriver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='main-nav-menu']/li[@class='dropdown-nav']//following::ul[1]//li/a"));
for(WebElement val:listValues)
    System.out.println(val.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

This code block gives me an output as:

```
  NA LCS

  EU LCS

  LCK

  LPL

  LMS

  NA Challenger

  EU Challenger

  Rift Rivals

  Mid-Season Invitational

  All-Star Event
```

Now you can do any assertion on the obtained `List`